# Java method definition

Tags: java, method-declaration

My code is like:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CalcPyramidVolume {


public static void pyramidVolume (double baseLength, double baseWidth, double pyramidHeight) {
  double volume;
  volume = baseLength * baseWidth * pyramidHeight * 1/3;
  return;
}

public static void main (String [] args) {
  System.out.println("Volume for 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 is: " + pyramidVolume(1.0, 1.0, 1.0));
  return;
}
}
```

And it said the print can't be done in the void type. I just don't understand why...

Comment: How has the user name "Gui" not been taken until now?

Comment: @Carcigenicate Usernames are [not unique](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253537/why-are-usernames-not-unique-here-on-stack-overflow) on StackOverflow.

Comment: @Jesper Oh wow, I never noticed that before. Given it's been like a year since I joined, that's kind of sad :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *void* method does not return anything you could append to that String in the main method. You would need to make the method return a *double* and then return your variable *volume*:

```
public static double pyramidVolume (double baseLength, double baseWidth, double pyramidHeight) {
  double volume;
  volume = baseLength * baseWidth * pyramidHeight * 1/3;
  return volume;
}
```

or shorter:

```
public static double pyramidVolume (double baseLength, double baseWidth, double pyramidHeight) {
  return baseLength * baseWidth * pyramidHeight * 1/3;
}
```

Also see: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Keywords/void

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using a function `pyramidVolume` that basically returns nothing. This should work:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CalcPyramidVolume {


public static double pyramidVolume (double baseLength, double baseWidth, double pyramidHeight) {
  double volume;
  volume = baseLength * baseWidth * pyramidHeight * 1/3;
  return volume;
}

public static void main (String [] args) {
  System.out.println("Volume for 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 is: " + pyramidVolume(1.0, 1.0, 1.0).toString());
  return;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CalcPyramidVolume {
    public static double pyramidVolume (double baseLength, double baseWidth, double pyramidHeight) {
        double volume;
        volume = baseLength * baseWidth * pyramidHeight * 1/3;
        return volume;
    }

    public static void main (String [] args) {
        System.out.println("Volume for 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 is: " + CalcPyramidVolume.pyramidVolume(1.0, 1.0, 1.0));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate on your code, explaining what it does and why it solves the problem